# Can't detect when user close a Chrome alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome

I have a problem with users submitting multiple forms if the connection is slow and they keep pressing a "submit" button.

I have 2 submit buttons, one is called "Next" and the other is called "Previous". Both buttons submit form data and then redirect to the appropriate page.

In order to prevent the form from being submitted duplicate times, I needed to disable the submit buttons. However, if the dom has changed and I use jquery's `$('form').submit()`, Chrome display an alert, warning the user that they are leaving the page. If the user decides to stay on the page by clicking the "stay" button, the dialog closes but I have no way of knowing. My buttons remain disabled.

```
$("#button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".btn").attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

However, if this message pops up if the form has been altered:

> **Do you want to leave this site?**
>
> Changes you made may not be saved.
>
> <kbd>Leave</kbd> <kbd>Stay</kbd>

If the user decides to stay, my buttons can not be re-enabled.

It doesn't seem like I can override the `window.onbeforeunload` event because the terrible web code I inherited is already doing something with that event and I don't want to break current functionality.

Is there a way to detect what the user selected on that chrome dialog in order to re-enable my buttons?

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anber500/6uc25by5/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that you can listen to if user decides to stay but you could enable the buttons inside `onbeforeunload` callback in case they do